# Run code after Spring context has been initialized in web app deployed on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I have a web application which I package as a war and I deploy on tomcat 7.

This is a Spring MVC application that I want to add a Quartz scheduler to it. I want to run code that will make use of various Spring beans and populates the scheduler with Jobs that are configured dynamically so I need access to various Beans in code like

```
 @Autowired
 private CronDAO cronDAO;     

 public void loadCronJobs(final Scheduler scheduler) {
    LOGGER.info("Vas[{}]: Loading Cron Schedule...", vasName);
    final List<Cron> crons = cronDAO.fetchAll();
    final Long cronSid = cron.getSid();
    final String directive = cron.getDirective();
    final String expression = cron.getCronExpression();
    ...
 }
```

Normally I would put the initialization code for the scheduler in the main function of the application and would use Autowired beans for my application logic. Now with the application server initializing the application I cannot do this.

I tried to add my code to the startup function of the servlet but the Spring context is not yet ready so the autowired beans (the DAO in this example) fail to load.

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

 @Override
 public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
  CronManager cron = new CronManagerImpl();
  cron.loadCronJobs();
 }
}
```

Is there a way to run code (not only quartz related) when the application start in the container but the Spring context to be complete?

Comment: Why aren't you simply using the build in JDBC support of quartz, you are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Annotate one of your bean methods with `@PostConstruct`, and do the initialization in that method. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations

Comment: That doesn't guarantee that the full context is loaded. Better to use an `ApplicationListener` and listen for `ContextRefreshedEvent`s. But even better would be to use the quartz JDBC storage instead of rolling his own.

Comment: I am new both to Spring and Quartz so I have no idea how the JDBC support of quartz would help me. But even as such the DAO bean is only one autowired bean whereas further down the code I have more beans that need context info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a 'ServletContextListener' and register it in the web.xml. In your implementation you can rely on spring frameworks WebApplicationContextUtil to get a handle to the spring application context.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

public class QuartzInitiator implements ServletContextListener {

     public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
            WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContextEvent.getServletContext())
           .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
          //your logic
     }
}
```

Autowired fields would be correctly initialized by the Util.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is great at avoiding you do deal with low level questions.

At higher level you have :

- a number of beans declared in Spring application context
- an initialization procedure that must be run

  - after the beans have been initialized
  - before the rest of code is run

Well simply declare a new bean in which you inject all the other beans, and do your initialization in the init-method of that last bean. Spring guarantees that this method is called at context initialization time after all dependant beans have been initialized.

That way is totally independant of whether your application is a web application or not : is becomes spring framework's problem and no longer yours.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this technique? Thanks